# How do network shares work in Windows 10?

Tags: windows-10, network-shares

Can someone please explain to me how network shares work in Windows 10 and why I cannot access a drive in my own home network even though the username and password are correct?

Or what is my username anyway from the point of view of Windows 10? Is it my email address or what windows 10 shows as a username (my name) or the name in the path to my folders?

In Windows 7, it was previously possible to access the corresponding shared network drive with the simple user name (for example tim) and the corresponding password. Does that have anything to do with these *domains*?

Of course I set up everything as suggested in various tutorials (explicit sharing of a specific folder for a specific user...)

Comment: 1. Make sure Network Discovery and File / Print Sharing are enabled on both computers.
 2. Make sure password protected sharing is enabled both computers.
 3. Make sure both computers are in the same WORKGROUP.
 4. Make sure Wireless connections are Private, not Public.
If using Microsoft Accounts, the above should work. You may need to share a folder (folder sharing properties) so the other machine can access it.

Comment: If you share the required folder, you should be able to open it from the other machine. I do that here.

Comment: Thanks but have double checked now:
1. It is enbaled, 'we' can see another.
3. They are both in the default 'WORKGROUP'
4. The network connection is marked as private on both

Only about your second point i am not sure, i will check that.

For now its not working. neither from my windows 10 laptop nor from my old windows 7 pc from which i want to back up my data :D. Its only possible when i am logged in with my 'online' windows account if you know what i mean. It seams to be not possible with a 'local' account.

Comment: Set up a user from the other machine on the Local machine (users and groups) and share a folder on the local machine. It is very possible to do. My desktop is a Local user and my laptop is a Microsoft User. Use mapped drives and map by IP address of the Local machine.

Comment: If i get you right, then i have to use the same user on both? Can you access a folder on your laptop with the local desktop user? I would have hoped it would also be possible as a different person (not the one for whom the share was set up) to access the network share as long as I have the password (and the corresponding username). Or did I get it wrong?

Comment: On a workgroup networks, individual accounts with same name and password must exist on both machines .

Comment: You can have different accounts but one machine must have the name / password of the other machine using Users and Groups.  Then folders can be shared to tha name.  I put that detail in my answer. It can be very flexible and all work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a complete set of instructions that I have used for years and I know to be working.

Try the tested steps below. Check through all, although some settings may already be in place:

Note: When connecting machines, Home Group is gone (security concerns), SMBv1 is gone, and Network Browsing at the Workstation level can be unreliable. Try it but also try mapping folders traditionally.

The following instructions enable folder sharing between two Windows 10 Machines

Operating System Settings (Review the settings below or change as needed):

1. Make sure Network Discovery and File / Print Sharing are enabled on both computers.
2. Make sure password protected sharing is enabled both computers.
3. Make sure both computers are in the same WORKGROUP.
4. Make sure Wireless connections are Private, not Public.

Alternative to Domain DNS name recognition:

1. If you wish to share by computer name instead of IP address, put an entry in the HOSTS file of the computer you are connecting from with the name and IP address of the main computer.

Setting up Sharing of folders:

1. This next step depends on computer user names and passwords. If both computers use the same username and password, you can skip this step, restart both and test.
2. If the user names are different, do the following:
3. Make a username on the Main (Sharing) Computer that is the user name and password of the computer you are connecting from. Use this for permissions on the folders on Main (Sharing) Computer you wish to share.

**Note:** It is normally quite difficult to share USER folders because Home Group was removed and USER folders are heavily secured. Use a neutral folder for sharing.

4. Again after all the above changes restart and test.

Testing the connection:

1. On the computer you are connecting from, open a command prompt and type:

NET USE X: \name_of_sharing_computer\folder

2. Press enter and then authenticate with the user name and password credentials.

If the connection attempt results in a numerical error, post that error back

Comment: Ok, the crucial point was the different usernames. But I don't understand what the point is and why windows then asks me which username I want to log in with. That doesn't make sense if the selection is limited to the accounts actually available locally, especially because it suggests I could type in any one. One more question about DNS recognition: This seems to be already activated for me because I can type in the name of the PC (for example \\NAS-PC\folder) and then I am prompted to login. Does that have something to do with network discovery or why do I apparently not need the HOSTS entry?

Comment: Names:  Just enumerate the name you want (Users and Groups) on the system you wish to access. It does not matter whether Windows uses Local or Microsoft Account. I use both.  HOSTS entry is used when DNS recognition is not available (most home/small systems). It is not related to Network Discovery.

Comment: Wow, i like this forum: good and fast feedback :)

Ok, then it is probably a feature of my router that I can simply use \\NAS-PC\folder to access. 

I'm not sure which answer to mark as the accepted one because both were useful but I think yours fits the specific question better. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

> what is my username anyway from the point of view of windows 10? Is it my email address or what windows 10 shows as a username (my name) or the name in the path to my folders?

If you signed in using a Microsoft Account from the beginning, then it's *probably* the email address.

If you originally created a local (non-MS) account, then it's the username you used (exactly as in previous Windows versions) – even if the account was later converted to MS Account mode.

Run the command `net user` (Cmd) or `Get-LocalUser` (PowerShell) or `lusrmgr.msc` (graphical) to see a list of all local usernames on your computer.

Looking at your user folders' path is not reliable, because accounts can be renamed – but the user folders *do not* get automatically renamed when that happens.

> In Windows 7, it was previously possible to access the corresponding shared network drive with the simple user name (for example tim) and the corresponding password. Does that have anything to do with these 'domains'?

Only on large enterprise / university networks, where accounts are centrally managed using Active Directory. If the computer is in "workgroup" mode, then it does not belong to a domain. Even if you're using a Microsoft Account, that's still just a special type of a local account – it does not have a separate domain.

(Though, internally, local accounts act as if they belonged to a domain named after the computer itself. So if you're connecting to a standalone/workgroup Windows system, and are prompted for a domain name, that computer's name will usually work.)